# Comparing two tables with a LIKE and CONCAT %

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, sql-like, concatenation

I have two tables

**USERS**  Contains user data

Mobilephone
447777744444
447777755555
7777755555
7777766666

**MOBILEPHONES** Contains mobile phone numbers

Telephone No
7777744444
7777733333
7777755555
7777766666

If I run the follow SQL it returns ONLY numbers that match exactly and does not perform the wildcard search.

```
SELECT MobilePhones.*, users.FirstName FROM MobilePhones
LEFT JOIN users
ON (users.MobilePhone= MobilePhones.`Telephone No`)
WHERE users.MobilePhone LIKE CONCAT('%', MobilePhones.`Telephone No`, '%')
```

I get returned

7777755555
7777766666

What I want is

7777755555
7777766666
447777755555
447777744444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to move your `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause of the join, replacing the existing `ON` clause, which is doing the exact match:

```
SELECT MobilePhones.*, users.FirstName 
FROM MobilePhones
LEFT JOIN users ON users.MobilePhone LIKE CONCAT('%', MobilePhones.`Telephone No`, '%')
```